# Custom styling in WebVTT subtitles

Tags: css, webvtt, video-subtitles, vtt

Is it possible to set custom styling for specific fragments in WebVTT (`.vtt`) subtitles?

According to the mozilla's [WebVTT API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API#styling_webvtt_cues) it is possible to set CSS pseudo-classes e.g. with:

```css
/* this works ok */
video::cue {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: rgb(255, 200, 0);
}

/* this does not work! */
video::cue(b) {
  color: red;
}
```

and then apply that style in the `.vtt` file with:

```
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:10.000
- Hello <b>world</b>.
```

In all browsers I've tried `<b>world</b>` is rendered with the same styling as regular video cues. I.e. the rule for the `video::cue` pseudo-class is applied and works as expected, while `video::cue(b)` has no effect.

I have tried defining the CSS pseudo classes in both the `<style/>` block of the HTML page as well as inside the VTT file itself as given in [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API#styling_webvtt_cues):

```
WEBVTT

STYLE
::cue {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: rgb(255, 200, 0);
}

STYLE
::cue(b) {
  color: red;
}
```

According to https://caniuse.com/webvtt modern browsers support webvtt and it's only Firefox that is/was missing support for the `::cue(<selector>)` pseudo-class.

Why is `<b>world</b>` not rendering with custom styling and is there a workaround?

Comment: I think you have to change the subtitle text: 
- Hello <b>world</b>.
to 
- Hello <c.b>world</c>.
See Example22 class selector
https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/#the-vttcue-interface

Answer (score 1):

It works as advertised in latest versions of safari, chrome, firefox and derivates.

Browsers are aggressively caching `.vtt` files and a cache purge solved the issue.

As outlined in https://www.w3.org/wiki/VTT_Concepts#Cue_Payload_Tags only three tags are supported, `<b>`, `<i>` and `<u>`, but it is also possible to style via CSS classes:

```css
/* the HTML file containing the video */
video::cue {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #ffc800;
}

video::cue(b) {
    color: rgb(51, 216, 18);
    font-weight: normal;
}

video::cue(i) {
    color: #00bafd;
    font-style: normal;
}

video::cue(u) {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ff00ee;
    font-style: normal;
}

video::cue(.myclass) {
    color: red;
}
```

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:11.040
<b>bold</b>
<i>italic</i>
<u>underscored</u>
<c.myclass>Styled</c>
```